# System.BadImageFormatException when installing service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am getting below exception when I try to run installer to set up service:

```
# ./InstallUtil ../../../../Applications/GasPosApp/bin/Wrapper.exe -s ../../../
../Applications/GasPosApp/properties/DispenserViewerApplication.wrapper.conf
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Exception occurred while initializing the installation:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Appl
ications\GasPosApp\bin\Wrapper.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was e
xpected to contain an assembly manifest..
```

Comment: This exception is thrown when you mix 32 and 64 bits assemblies. Try to compile all projects in AnyCPU.

Comment: I am just running this from command prompt. could you please till how to over this?

Comment: @user1280096 You have all the information you need in answers. Just use the other version of InstallUtil and you will be fine.

Comment: Type "where installutil.exe" and tells us what you see.

Answer (score 19):

You have to use the right version of the InstallUtil. If you are trying install a 32 bit service (x86), use

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
```

and if you are installing a 64 bit service (x64), use

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
```

Note, that the last specified folder (v4.0.30319) may differ a machine from machine. If you have only an older version of the framework available you can encounter one of the following folders instead - v1.0.xxxx, v1.1.xxxx, v2.0.xxxxx, v3.0, v3.5.

Comment: I am using the c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe to install 32 bit service.

Comment: @user1280096 And you still get that error? I don't think so. Please, verify that your services is really 32 bit.

Comment: how does ony uses a specific version of the installUtil ?

Comment: @UncleDaveIsWatching It's a manual operation so you choose the version you have installed and use that one. If this doesn't answer your question can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

This is often an indication of a mismatch between 32 and 64 bit. For instance if `Wrapper.exe` is compiled as x86 and you install it using the 64 bit `InstallUtil` the process cannot load the 32 bit `Wrapper.exe` assembly and will throw a `BadImageFormatException`.

The solution is to use the 32 bit `InstallUtil` placed in the `Framework` (not `Framework64`) subfolder of the .NET folder (e.g. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\v4.0.30319\Framework` if you are using .NET 4 or 4.5).

Comment: I am using the .NET 4.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with all here! This error come, if you are trying to load your application or a one of the refreanced assemblies in an invalid operating system format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception(v=vs.80).aspx

- Check your opearting system format? x86 or x64
- Check your project build configuration?
- Check all refreanced assebmlies (VERY IMPORTENET) if one of your loaded refreances (DLL's) is built in the wrong format you will get this error also (Correct me if I'm wrong!).
- If possible change your VS buid configurartion to AnyCpu.

Microsoft has created useful tool called CorFlags which can be used to show or set the targeted platform of an managed assembly.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0\Bin\CorFlags.exe

Syntax:
CorFlags filename

```
**anycpu** 
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 1
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 0 

**x86**
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 3
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 1
Signed    : 0 

**x64** 
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32+
CorFlags  : 1
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 0
```